# Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError:

Tags: angular, typescript

I am getting confused by this error where I have `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` error, I have tried to understand `ngAfterContentInit` but I am not sure how can I use that in my case, if someone can let me know why is this problem occuring. the `_state` are used to prevent cyclic calls.

```
  private password_disabled: any;
  private sudo: any;
  private locked: any;
  private password_disabled_state = false;
  private sudo_state = false;
  private locked_state = false;


 constructor(.....) {}


  afterInit(entityForm: any) {
    this.isNew = entityForm.isNew;
    this.password_disabled = entityForm.formGroup.controls['password_disabled'];
    this.sudo = entityForm.formGroup.controls['sudo'];
    this.locked = entityForm.formGroup.controls['locked'];

    this.password_disabled.valueChanges.subscribe((password_disabled)=>{
      if(password_disabled && !this.sudo_state && !this.locked_state){
        entityForm.setDisabled('sudo', password_disabled);
        entityForm.setDisabled('locked', password_disabled);
        this.password_disabled_state = password_disabled;
      } else {
        this.password_disabled_state = !this.password_disabled_state;
        entityForm.setDisabled('sudo', !this.sudo_state);
        entityForm.setDisabled('locked', !this.locked_state);

      }
    })
    this.locked.valueChanges.subscribe((locked)=>{
      if(locked && !this.password_disabled_state){
        entityForm.setDisabled('password_disabled', locked);
        this.locked_state = locked;
      }
      else{
        this.locked_state = !this.locked_state;
      }
    });

    this.sudo.valueChanges.subscribe((sudo)=>{
      if(sudo && !this.password_disabled_state){
        entityForm.setDisabled('password_disabled', sudo);
        this.sudo_state = sudo;
      }
      else{
        this.sudo_state = !this.sudo_state;
      }
    });

ERROR Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'id: true'. Current value: 'id: false'.
```

Comment: The presence of all those flags is a serious design smell. You're likely  to run into all sorts of issues and your logic will not be maintainable

Comment: hmm, ok I agree but this is what I have at this moment. suggest me a better approach if you like :)

Comment: well... storing things both in form fields and as properties of the component class is a bad idea

Answer (score 0):

This will likely resolve itself if you changed from `afterInit` to `ngOnInit`. It is erroring because the html has just been generated from the component template, but then you are modifying values that were used to generate the html. so it complains at you with this error.

`ngOnInit` on the other hand will allow for modifying these values prior to the html being generated from the template.

---

From the spec:

> `ngAfterContentInit()`
>   Respond **after Angular projects external content into the component's view** / the view that a directive is in. Called once after the first ngDoCheck().
>
> `ngOnInit()`
>   Initialize the directive/component after Angular first displays the data-bound properties and sets the directive/component's input properties. Called once, after the first ngOnChanges().

---

Personally, I don't use `ngAfterContentInit()` unless I am trying to query the DOM for some element and then act on it, like a Jquery animation or something alon those lines.